# C# initializing a constructor using : this

Tags: c#

Why `this` doesn't accept a parameter of a class-type? What can I read about it? Here is my useless code

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
  public int a = 5;
}

public class Class2
{
  private readonly int num;
  Class1 obj2 = new Class1();
  public Class2(Class1 obj)
  {
    num = obj.a;
  }
  public Class2(string l) : this (Class1 obj2)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `public Class2(string l) : this (obj2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor takes an instance of `Class1`, so you should use:

```
public Class2(string l) : this (new Class1())
{
}
```

You will probably also want to assign the constructor argument to your `obj2` member instead of creating a new one:

```
public class Class2
{
    private readonly int num;
    Class1 obj2;
    public Class2(Class1 obj)
    {
        this.obj2 = obj;
        num = obj.a;
    }
    public Class2(string l) : this (new Class1()) { }
}
```

Comment: Lee can you tell me what can i read about this? what's the name of the subject, how to ask the google?

Comment: @user1884807 - Calling one constructor from another is called 'constructor chaining' I believe.

Comment: still confused though (new Class1()) this instance is without a reference if i inderstand right, didn't know the instance could be without a reference, isn't that when GC shows up?

Comment: @user1884807 - It will be referenced by the `obj` parameter in the other constructor so it won't get collected.

Answer (score 2):

First let's look at:

```
public Class2(string l) : this (Class1 obj2) {...}
```

Firstly, you don't include the type in an invocation, so it would be:

```
public Class2(string l) : this (obj2) {...}
```

But: `obj2` *is not valid* at that point: the constructor (which kinda includes the field initializer) *has not run yet*, so fields on `this` (such as `this.obj`) are not legal at that location. as Lee notes: just pass in a `null` or `new` instance.

Comment: why i don't have to indicate the type of invocation here? it's true only for :this parameters?

Comment: @user1884807 it is the same as any method call: you don't call `int i = Math.Min(int 1, int 3)` - you call `int i = Math.Min(1,3)`

Answer (score 0):

A class can inherit from another class. The `this` keyword refers to an instance of a class and instances do not exist at "develop-time"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that `string` and pass it to another contructor that takes `Class1`  as argument. You need to create a `Class1` object. But since that needs an `int` i would not use a constructor that takes `string` but `int`. Otherwise you would need to use `int.Parse` which could throw an excption and exceptional constructors are not good practise(when they could be avoided).

```
public Class2(int i)
    : this(new Class1() { a=i })
{

}
```